# Are there cummulative updates for "Language Pack for SharePoint Foundation 2010"?

Tags: 2010

I installed the SP1 for each language pack and i cannot find any cummulative updates for the language packs. Do they exist or am i up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no CUs for language packs.